# Url based content filtering in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, filtering, content-type

I have searched long and far for a plugin that would allow me to filter content on a page based on url extension so for example wwww.examcple.com/stuff/us will display only stuff relevant to US; there is a wordpress plugin that allows me to do this using IP https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-content-by-country/.

but is there one that would allow me to do the exact same thing using the URL? does somone know of a way of doing this using HTML only?

Comment: you mean like getting current page or what which page url you needed?

Comment: so if on any normal page url if there is an extention like www.example.com/page?special123 display the specil content on that page if not than just show normal page